# python における import 文のスタイルに関して

Tags: python, matplotlib, coding-style

質問は２つあります
１．

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

ではなく

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

と書くのはなぜですか？

２．
２通りの書き方ができるなら普段はどちら（from を使う使わない）を使うべきですか？

既に同じ質問がありましたら申し訳ございません

Answer (score 1, accepted):

丁度こちらに同様の記事がありました。
[Is “from matplotlib import pyplot as plt” == “import matplotlib.pyplot as plt”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30558087/9014308)

質問への回答としては、1.tutorialにそう書いてあるから。2.どちらでもお好みで。でしょう。
(回答者は下側の方が良いと考えています) google翻訳結果を載せておきます。

> それらは同等ですが、pltとしての2番目の形式import matplotlib.pyplotの方が客観的に読みやすいという、かなり良い議論があると思います。
>
> 1.一般的にはpltとしてimport matplotlib.pyplotを使用し、matplotlibドキュメンテーション（http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.htmlなどを参照）で推奨されているので、これはほとんどの読者にとってより身近なものになるでしょう。
>
> 2.matplotlib.pyplotはpltが短いほどインポートされますが、それほど明確ではありません。
>
> 3.pltとしてmatplotlib.pyplotをインポートすることは、なじみのない読者に、pyplotが最初の形式から誤って想定される可能性がある関数ではなくモジュールであるというヒントを与えます。
>
> コメント: matplotlibはパッケージで、本質的には関連モジュールの集合です。 最も簡単に言うと、パッケージは空の__init__.pyファイルを持つモジュールファイルを含むディレクトリにすることができます。このファイルは、そのディレクトリをパッケージとして扱うことをpythonに指示します。 パッケージA内のモジュールB（つまり、ファイル構造A / B.py）は、インポートA.Bとしてインポートされます。

日本語でimportの使い方の記事がありました。
[Python, importの使い方（from, as, PEP8の推奨スタイル, 注意点など）](https://note.nkmk.me/python-import-usage/)

開発元の推奨スタイルがあるようです。
[PEP 8 imports -- Style Guide for Python Code | Python.org](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)

Comment: お好みで！ということなら、from派ですねー。疑問が解決いたしました。ありがとうございます。